# Random Shuffle without getting same results again

Tags: php, mysql

```
id    |  photo title     |  created_date

33 |  my family       |  2009 8 04
44  |  friends group   |  2009 4 05
55  |  beautiful place |  2009 3 06
66  |  working late    |  2009 11 07
```

I randomized my results and limited by 1. Say I have the id `55`.  How would I get the next row without getting the results I got again?

This is the query for the homepage

> SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1

For the next pages I might get the same results again

> SELECT * FROM data WHERE id > $n ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1

Comment: You can pass the result of query to another page via `$_SESSION`

Comment: The session could be too big if the database is getting larger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reuse a seed that you generate in PHP.

Pseudo code:

```
$seed = rand()
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY RAND(?) LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param($seed);
$stmt->execute()
...
```

And then when you need the rest of the rows:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY RAND(?) LIMIT 2,1000");
$stmt->bind_param($seed);
$stmt->execute()
...
```

See more about seeding `RAND()` in [the mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand).

The advantage of this approach is that you can display any number of pages without having to keep track of anything but the initially generated seed (and of course which page you're on).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write what engine you use. Assuming it's pdo you can use fetchAll() on the results and pass the result of fetchAll() to session via $_SESSION;

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY rand() ");
$sth->execute();
$_SESSION['rnd_res'] = $sth->fetchAll();
```

If you write `LIMIT 1` there will be no other records just one. You can also remember the last id or groups of id and write

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE id<>$last_id ORDER BY rand()
```

this will exclude the last id you used, this id may be stored in `$_SESSION` as well.

Last option for group of results may be `NOT IN()` in query;

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE id NOT IN($array_of_last_ids) ORDER BY rand()
```

Comment: How I wish we could all assume everyone uses PDO :P

Comment: I'm not using POD, just PHP and MySQL :(

Comment: PDO is a php engine that connect with DataBase for example MySQL. @Lix I wish too ;P

Answer (score 0):

Well, one option would be to provide the results you have already selected in the where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE `id` NOT IN ('the', 'ids', 'you', 'already', 'selected', ...) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

However this approach will quite rapidly become inefficient as more and more "used ids" get added to the `NOT IN` list. This will always be a problem when dealing with random results.

You might want to consider storing the used id values in a separate table and using the contents of that table (possibly indexed by user_id) for specifying the already used results.