# Select a random value from an array after a selection from database

Tags: php, sql, arrays, random

I'm trying to get a random value from an array that is populated with data from the database. I'm selecting some products from the DB and display them on the front page, but i need to display different (random) producs everytime the page is reloaded.

```
$row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anunt WHERE lichidareStoc = 0 ORDER BY anuntID DESC") or die(mysql_error());
$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($row);
```

So, i think that $row2 is now an array, and has all the infos that i selected previously from the database. How do i select a random 'row' from that array now?

Thanks

Comment: You could make the database do the work for you, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928079/return-random-results-order-by-rand/16928464#16928464 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928019/random-shuffle-without-getting-same-results-again/16928182#16928182.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select a random entry, you could do something like this:

```
$myRows=array();
$row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anunt WHERE lichidareStoc = 0 ORDER BY anuntID DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($row))
    $myRows[]=$row2;

$randomEntry=$myRows[array_rand($myRows)];
```

If you wanted a random field of that entry though, you should use [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) like Bernhard Poiss pointed out.

```
$row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anunt WHERE lichidareStoc = 0 ORDER BY anuntID DESC") or die(mysql_error());
$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($row);
$randomField=$row2[array_rand($row2)];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `array_rand`, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Example:

```
$rand_key = array_rand($row2);
echo $row2[$rand_key]; // your random
```

You could also directly select a random row from your DB:

```
SELECT * 
FROM anunt
WHERE lichidareStoc = 0
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 1
```

But be aware, this will reduce your performance, especially on bigger tables.

**Side Note: mysql_* function are deprecated, use mysqli_* instead.**

Answer (score 0):

You will first want to populate an array of your results

```
$row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anunt WHERE lichidareStoc = 0 ORDER BY anuntID DESC") or die(mysql_error());
$rows = array();
while($rec =  mysql_fetch_assoc($row)){
    $rows[] = $rec;
}
```

Then you can select a random item using array_rand

```
$random = $rows[array_rand($rows)];
```